# Calling argc/argv function with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I am creating a wrapper to a code in c for Python. The c code basically runs in terminal and has the following main function prototype:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
f=fopen(argv[1],"r");
f2=fopen(argv[2],"r");
```

So basically arguments read are strings in terminal. I created following python ctype wrapper, but it appears I am using wrong type. I know the arguments passed from the terminal is read as characters but an equivalent python side wrapper is giving following error:

```
import ctypes
_test=ctypes.CDLL('test.so')

def ctypes_test(a,b):
  _test.main(ctypes.c_char(a),ctypes.c_char(b))

ctypes_test("323","as21")



TypeError: one character string expected
```

I have tried adding one character, just to check if shared object gets executed, it does as print commands work but momentarily till the section of the code in shared object needs file name. I also tried 
 `ctypes.c_char_p` but get.

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

---

Updated as per the suggestion in the comments to the following:

```
def ctypes_test(a,b):
      _test.main(ctypes.c_int(a),ctypes.c_char_p(b))
ctypes_test(2, "323 as21")
```

Yet getting the same error.

Comment: Why are you passing completely different arguments to `main` than what's declared in its signature?

Comment: `main` takes an int and a char**. You're trying to pass it two chars.

Comment: You're not running an executable from a command line. You're calling a function.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica revisiting your comments and made changes, I added `test.main(ctypes.c_int(a),ctypes.c_char_p(b))` but the issue persists

Comment: Okay, look. If you had a function `int foo(int argc, char *argv[])` in a C program, and you wanted to call that function, in C, what would you do?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica `foo(2,&p)`, where `p` is the address of some string. Also I have updated the question and deleted some of my comments to make room for more of your suggestions

Comment: For `main`, the first argument represents the number of strings, so you'd want to pass in an array of two strings as the second argument, something like `char *argv[] = {"323", "as21"}; foo(2, argv)`. (Actually, `argv[argc]` is required to be a null pointer, and argument 0 is supposed to be the program name, so it'd have to be more like `char *argv[] = {"progname", "323", "as21", NULL}; foo(3, argv)`.) The key point is that all of the strings go through the second argument. You don't try to stuff one into the first argument.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes, you have identified the problem correct. What I was missing was that the first argument is supposed to be the program name itself with is `argv[0]` in my case was `./test.out`, I added this dummy placement holder for argument 0 and now it works like a charm! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using this test DLL for Windows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

This code will call it.  `argv` is basically a `char**` in C, so the `ctypes` type is `POINTER(c_char_p)`.  You also have to pass bytes strings and it can't be a Python list.  It has to be an array of `ctypes` pointers.

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> dll = CDLL('./test')
>>> dll.main.restype = None
>>> dll.main.argtypes = c_int, POINTER(c_char_p)
>>> args = (c_char_p * 3)(b'abc', b'def', b'ghi')
>>> dll.main(len(args), args)
abc
def
ghi
```

Comment: +1 Mark, you are amazing! With your working example I figured out that I dont have to create a shared object `.so`, I can simply use the executable file `.out` and work with it in python. Secondly, I also figured that in command-line the `argv[0]` is the execution command `./test.out` itself! I simply added that as dummy argument in python, so all the other arguments simply shifted 1 step ahead and now it works like a charm! I would not have had figured this out myself, thanks again for the worked example!

Comment: I have one follow up though. My return type is `c_int` and in the code I add `dll.main.restype = c_int`, the c-code executes fine and I get all the prints that c-code executes, but in the end in python, I get `Process finished with exit code 14` instead of the int return, which I need to print. Is this a known issue?

Comment: @gfdsal `ctypes` is meant for so/dll. If calling a process you can use the `subprocess` module.  You are seeing the exit code of Python, not the executable’s exit code. To see the return of a ctypes function, use `retval = func()` and print that.