# Segmentation fault from Shared Object C/Python

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, ctypes

I want to use C code from Python with ctypes. The code is from open-plc-tools/slac/evse.c. It works completely normal when I compile it without calling it from ctypes. This is the Python code:

```
from ctypes import *

so_file = "/home/evse/open-plc-utils/slac/evse.so"

evse = CDLL(so_file)

evse.main()
```

Running it without sudo returns:

```
python3: eth1: Operation not permitted
```

Running it with sudo results in a Segmentation fault.

I have experience with Python but not so much with normal C, only some experience with this Arduino mixed language (C/C++). I read it has to do something with (NULL) pointers, but I don't know how to interpret this.

Comment: `main` expects `argc` and `argv` parameters.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62422953/235698 for a `ctypes` example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mark Tolonen for the hint. I found a solution here:

[Calling argc/argv function with ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418314/calling-argc-argv-function-with-ctypes)

This is the entry point on the code, which works now as intended.

```
from ctypes import *

so_file = "/home/evse/open-plc-utils/slac/evse.so"

evse = CDLL(so_file)

evse.main.restype = None
evse.main.argtypes = c_int,POINTER(c_char_p)
args = (c_char_p * 1)(b'c')
evse.main(len(args),args)
```

Thank you!